# Required servo control current

Tags: microprocessor, servo

When using a mini servo (3 wire) for RC models, I've found both designs which connect the signal wire straight to a 555 chip and some that do it via a simple transistor off the 5V line.

I haven't seen the required current mentioned anywhere at all in specs I've seen actually. If it is mentioned, it's only something like "this is signal pin, it uses almost no power".

So is it safe to assume that I can control a servo directly from an output / PWM port of ATTiny working at 5V? (servo power is supplied separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally the PWM input wire of a RC servo would never sink or source any current, it would have infinite impedance. The signal input of a real world servo can draw or source some current and will have a certain amount of capacitance to ground and the power supply (the magnitudes depend on the design choices of each particular servo), but these parasitic effects are neglible in practice.

It is safe to assume that you can drive a servo directly from an output of an ATtiny. Most ATtiny chips can source or sink 20 mA, which is orders of magnitude more than the signal pin will ever draw. If you are still paranoid you can add a 280 ohm current limiting resistor between the servo signal input and the microcontroller pin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work fine from a microcontroller output. I don't see the input current specified for typical servo chips (eg. [M51660L](http://www.voti.nl/docs/M51660L.pdf)), but it's certainly not much.

They are intended to work from a logic level (>3V) output.